# Nginx + PHP-FPM Client Abort

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

Here's my config (Nginx 1.7.x) :

```
server {

    listen 8000;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    root /var/www/;
    server_tokens off;
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    }

}
```

And php-fpm config:

```
[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 6000;
pm.process_idle_timeout = 5;
chdir = /
security.limit_extensions = .php
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_flag[display_startup_errors] = on
```

I have a PHP script from which i send **LIVE DATA** to the client.. When the client closes the connection, I can see that **the PID is being closed after 15-20 seconds**. I think this is due to buffer and the way nginx works .

For example if I disable the nginx/fastcgi buffering **by setting fastcgi_buffering off** ***the connection of the client is being closed instantly***.

However, the nginx buffering is very important for me to reduce any lag from the client if found.

So is there any way that nginx/php can ***instantly*** get the event when a client disconnects even when I have the buffering on?

Thank you

Comment: Check that you did not override `fastcgi_ignore_client_abort` and that your buffer size is not too small. As you are using `fastcgi_keep_conn ` the connection should not be closed right after sending the reply anyway. A bit of `tcpdump` could be useful there too in order to see if php-fpm use `TCP_CORK` while the other part doesn't use `TCP_NODELAY`, that would explain this behaviour.